# Prepend category in SEO-friendly URL?

Tags: url, seo

I have a website that contains "items", which have an ID and title. They are divided into categories.

Category indexes are viewed at URL's like

```
example.com/tutorials
example.com/maps
```

What would be the best URL structure for the items themselves, from a SEO point of view and just semantically in general?

```
example.com/tutorials/12/Make+a+php+site
example.com/maps/29/Inside+the+moon
```

or

```
example.com/12/Make+a+php+site
example.com/29/Inside+the+moon
```

The category addition in the former is actually unnecessary. I only need the ID to find an item. However, I somehow feel the former is better.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The categories are very important SEO-relevant keywords, it would be better to have them in the URL, even if they are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with PeterP - just having /12/Make+a+php+site doesn't give any context to the reader or search engine. Also, IMHO, plus symbols are ugly. Use dashes instead (like SO) :-).

Answer (score 0):

I would use the most descriptive URL, without appending unnecessary information. If these are distinct categories in your website, available through separate menu items, I would use the

`http://www.example.com/Maps/12/Map-of-the-world`

form.

If 'map' or 'tutorial' are more like tags or classes that are not unique, or can be multiple per item, or have no separate landing page or menu item, I'm not so sure. Best to include the most basic relevant information, and from your example I would suggest including the category.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to argue the accepted answer to use categories in your url scheme, as they are sort of content-agnostic taxonomies.

Consider you have a movie information database web application like well-known IMDB. There, you have contents in these **fields**:

- Movie trailers
- Movie actors / actresses
- Film criticisms
- ...

and these **categories**:

- Action
- Comedy
- Adventure
- ...

using categories in your URLs you may have these URLs:

```
myimdb.com/action/ArnoldSchwarzenegger
myimdb.com/action/TheTerminator

myimdb.com/comedy/SomeLikeItHot
myimdb.com/comedy/MarilynMonroe
```

And obviously it does not make sense to put an **actor** and a **movie** on the same path. You may always have variety of content domains under same category, as categories are **content-agnostic taxonomies**.

So I suggest choosing URL schemes like:

```
example.com/12/Make+a+php+site
example.com/29/Inside+the+moon
```

just like Stack overflow did for its questions.